# Query multiple key values with Rails + Postgres hstore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I am trying to make a query to search for values in my hstore column properties. I am filtering issues by user input by attribute. It is possible to search Issues where email is X, or Issues where email is X and the sender is "someone". Soon I need to change to search using LIKE for similar results. So if you know how to do it with LIKE also, show both options please.

If I do this:

```
Issue.where("properties @> ('email => pugozufil@yahoo.com') AND properties @> ('email => pugozufil@yahoo.com')")
```

it returns a issue.

If I do this:

```
Issue.where("properties @> ('email => pugozufil@yahoo.com') AND properties @> ('sender => someone')")
```

Here I got an error, telling me:

```
ERROR:  Syntax error near 'd' at position 11
```

I change the "@>" to "->" and now this error is displayed:

`PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type text`

I need to know how to query the properties with more than one key/value pair, with "OR" or "AND", doesn't matter.

I wish to get one or more results that include those values I am looking for.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: @Cassio S. Cabral: Try this: `Issue.where("properties @> ? AND properties @> ?", ('email => pugozufil@yahoo.com'), ('sender => someone') )`

Comment: @anusha That worked when I tried query for 2 emails, using OR. Which is nice. But I am getting error with different fields. Can't figure out why exactly. Gonna try some more and come back later to give some more informations. Thanks for the comments anyway

Comment: @KevinSylvestre yes, I am just to trying to get something then change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I end up doing like this. Using the [array](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) option of the method where. Also using the suggestion from @anusha in the comments. IDK why the downvote though, I couldn't find anything on how to do something simple like this. I had doubt in formatting my query and mostly with hstore. So I hope it helps someone in the future as sure it did for me now.

```
if params[:filter].present?
    filters = params[:filter]
    conditions = ["properties -> "]
    query_values = []
    filter_query = ""
    filters.each do |k, v|
      if filters[k].present?
        filter_query += "'#{k}' LIKE ?"
        filter_query += " OR "
        query_values << "%#{v}%"
      end
    end
    filter_query = filter_query[0...-(" OR ".size)] # remove the last ' OR '
    conditions[0] += filter_query
    conditions = conditions + query_values
    @issues = @issues.where(conditions)
end
```